# Issue with two Dell R620 servers connected directly with Cat5e cable get slow speeds

Tags: networking, file-sharing, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to set up a new Hyper-V cluster to run my virtual environment on. Decided to try out 2019 and currently I have two HOST servers (Dell R620s) connected together using a cat5 cable directly (no switch).  Each host has a total of 4 NICs (2x10Gb and 2x1Gb).  The issue was really bad on one of the 10Gb NICs so I decided to do the tests on the 1Gb NICs on each server.

I have the other NICs connected to other things in my production environment but was getting mad about the slow speeds across the network so I wanted to do some testing...

HOST1 : 192.168.35.1
...directly connected to...
HOST2 : 192.168.35.2

On host1 I try to send over a large VM and this is the results...
[image]

Any idea what I might have configured wrong to make the network speed so bad?  I have also disabled VMQ on all NICs just to test things out.  Not sure if this is something with 2019 or maybe the NICs etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you NIC settings?  Did you try another cable, one that's known to be good?  *connected together using a cat5 cable* FWIW, you need cat6 for 10Gbase-T...

Comment: @AndrewHenle What NIC settings are you after specifically?  That's a very vague question.  Are you talking about IP settings, hardware settings like VMQ etc?  Yes, other cables were tried, and just to troubleshoot I have a strait cable connected from one NIC to the other eliminating the switch as a possible issue.  About the Cat6 comment, the strait cable (cat5e) was just for testing and was on a 1Gb, not 10Gb.  I just want to get speeds that are realistic for Cat5e though.  Something better than 30 MB/s.  ;)

Comment: Could be a book lying on a keyboard with any logged on workstation.